# Language/ format in Google Form changes from English to Arabic (partially) when Selenium Webdriver is controlling the MS Edge browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, microsoft-edge, google-forms

The language settings of my Windows desktop, Google account and MS Edge browser are `English (US)`. I live in UAE.

I have created my Google form in English. However, when I open the response page using `MS Edge browser` (using `Selenium webdriver`), while the form questions still appear in English, the alignment has changed to right to left, submit button turned to Arabic and also the form answer fields (the floating "your answer" text) appear in Arabic. I have tried many things suggested in Google support and MS Edge support forums. But not able to figure out the solution. Appreciate help here.

The code used thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
GFORM_LINK = "https://docs.google.com/forms/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
ser = Service("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=ser)
response_form = driver.get(url=GFORM_LINK)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the form show well in your Edge browser without using Selenium? If so, you can run Selenium with that specific profile you use in Edge.

First, you can find the profile path by navigating to *edge://version/*. You'll find the profile path like below:

[image]

Then you can back up your `User Data` folder in the same path. Here for example, I back up the `User Data` folder as `User Data1`:

[image]

Now you can use `User Data1` in your code to specify which profile to use when run Edge with Selenium:

```
edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

#Here you set the path of the back up profile ending with User Data1 not the profile folder 
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data1")

#Here you specify the actual profile folder
#If it's Default profile, no need to use this line of code
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=YourProfileDir") #e.g. Profile 1  

driver = webdriver.Edge(options = edge_options, service=ser)
```

---

**Update:**

The form shows in Arabic because you don't login google account in the form page. If there's no account login, the form page will show language according to geolocation. If an account login, the form page will show according to the language set in google account.

As a workaround, I think you can login after navigating to the form page, so that the form will show in English.

Comment: 1st question - Yes, it does show normally in Edge without using selenium. Adding edge option argument without the profile folder, either 'Default' or 'some other name, ex: 'Profile 2' with or without the optional code line '(edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")'  opens a new Edge window but the Google form is not loading. However, if I add a profile folder  at the end to the path, with or without the optional code line, a new edge window open and the form loads; but, the original problem of language and format continues.

Comment: @Srinivas I see. I came across the issue before, that's because there're running Edge processes in the background. Then specifying Edge profile in Selenium won't work. The solution is you can back up your `User Data` folder in the same path and use that folder in selenium. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Tried your revised suggestion with a new user data folder and a new profile folder inside it. But he problem persists as per my previous comment.

Comment: There must be some error if it doesn't proceed to the Google Form site. Could you please show me the error message? Besides, what is the profile path you're using in your Edge browser? Why do you have a new profile folder? You just need to copy and paste the `User Data` folder. You don't need to copy&paste or create a new profile folder.

Comment: There is no error message. Simply the edge browser controlled by selenium opens. I get the same 2nd screenshot in my original question post above (partially in Arabic). Below is the code I used as per what you suggested. I put some dummy text in the links below.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

GFORM_LINK = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/restofformaddress"

edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data1")
edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2") 

ser = Service("mypath/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=ser, options=edge_options)
driver.get(url=GFORM_LINK)

Comment: Not sure how I can put the above code in proper format in the comment box.

Comment: Your code format is correct. It should work if you're using the right profile. Could you please confirm again and provide the screenshot of your *edge://version/* page when you don't use selenium (you can hide the privacy information on the page)? Besides, you say your folder name is **partially in Arabic**, right? I'm not sure if there're some special characters in Arabic which leads to that the profile folder name can't be recognized. It's recommended to use English in folder names.

Comment: I did not say my folder name is partially in Arabic. The Google response form appears partially in Arabic. You may please see that in the original question. I have also attached the edge://version/ page when selenium is not used.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. From your newly posted screenshot, you're using the default profile. Then there's no need to set `profile-directory`. Please remove this line in your code `edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")`.

Comment: Never mind. As I have already mentioned in my previous post on 20th Jan the form appears partially in Arabic with or without  `edge_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2")`

Comment: I do some research and I find that the form shows in Arabic because you don't login google account in the form page. If there's no account login, the form page will show language according to geolocation. If an account login, the form page will show according to the language set in google account. As a workaround, I think you can login after navigating to the form page, so that the form will show in English.